# How to add horizontal image set in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi Im trying to make something like this. All the black balls are png images.
[image]

So far I tried this,

```
final bolabola = ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            width: 20.0,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/scoreballs/n1.png",),
              height: 25.0,
              width: 25.0,
            ),
        ),

        Container(
          width: 20.0,
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/scoreballs/n1.png",),
            height: 25.0,
            width: 25.0,
          ),
        )
      ],


    );
```

scrollDirection didnt work because I use a another list view to display all my components in the page.
How do I fix this?

Edit: my complete code is below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Live extends StatefulWidget{
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return LiveState();
  }
}

class LiveState extends State<Live> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Live button
    final livestatus = Chip(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        label: Text("LIVE",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    );

    //Status bar
    final status = Text("Richmond College won the toss and elected to bat first", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.center);

    //School Crest
    final crest = Image(
        image: AssetImage("assets/crest.png"),
        height: 79.0,
        width: 64.0,
    );

    final score = Text("182/4", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 73.0, color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.center,);

    final overs = Text("23.5 Overs", style:TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.center, );

    final scorecard = Text("Scorecard", style:TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.center, );

    final bolabola = ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            width: 20.0,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/scoreballs/n1.png",),
              height: 25.0,
              width: 25.0,
            ),
        ),

        Container(
          width: 20.0,
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/scoreballs/n1.png",),
            height: 25.0,
            width: 25.0,
          ),
        )
      ],


    );


/*
    final scoreballs = Image(
      image: AssetImage("assets/scoreballs/n1.png",),
      height: 25.0,
      width: 25.0,
    );

    */

        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                livestatus,
                SizedBox(height: 0.0),
                status,
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                crest,
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                score,
                overs,
                scorecard,
                bolabola,


              ],
            )
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: please add some more as you say you are using another list view add that to.

Comment: @viren Sure I added the complete code to the original post.

Comment: why don't you use - SingleChildScrollView ---     final bolabola = SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[ Container(
            width: 20.0,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/scoreballs/n1.png",),
              height: 25.0,
              width: 25.0,
            ),
        ), ....

Answer (score 0):

Add `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to `ListView` object. 
When using horizontal `scrollDirection` the `Container` object has to have height specified

The following code is from a project where i had to implement horizontal image carousel:

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        height: 200.0,
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), 
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row( 
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: _imagesWidget // this is a list containing Cards with image
            )
          ]
        ),
      );
```

Comment: I did. It throws an error. `I/flutter (25227): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (25227): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (25227): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1598 pos 16:
I/flutter (25227): 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.`

Comment: i added this to show you how i structured the code.. please just add the `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to `ListView` object

Comment: and also add the height property to `Container` object. I think that's the problem in your case

Comment: No. I already tried adding scrollDirection. You can see I commented that in mu code.Will try adding height to the container

Comment: added the height property. Didnt work yet. Same error throws out

Comment: give me an screenshot with your code.. I seen that you added a Container for each image.. Change `Center` to `Container` add height there and also if you add the `props` found in `Row` object you will get a horizontal centered list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184606/discussion-between-suvin-nimnaka-sukka-and-andrei-todorut).